# Winform Chart control - to keep displaying same bar width for different data

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I'm familiar with C# and Winform, but new to Chart control. I'm using VS2013 built in `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart` to display bar for two points. Here's simply the code:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Chart c = new Chart();
        c.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        ChartArea a = new ChartArea();
        a.AxisX.Minimum = 0;
        a.AxisX.Maximum = 4;
        a.AxisY.Minimum = 0;
        a.AxisY.Maximum = 2;

        c.ChartAreas.Add(a);

        Series s = new Series();
        //*******************
        s.Points.AddXY(1, 1);
        //s.Points.AddXY(2, 2);
        s.Points.AddXY(3, 2);
        //*******************
        c.Series.Add(s);

        this.Controls.Add(c);
    }
```

[image]
Please note the commented part, the points (2,2) and (3,2) are only different **data**, and have nothing to do with display **style**(I guess?). So this behavior seems very strange and so far I haven't found any solution to **keep displaying (3,2) like (2,2)**.

Comment: Check the below answer, I hope it solves your problem. I have deleted the comments as they are no longer required. I've used charts with asp.net but not with winforms so some things were different to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the below codes in order to achieve the desired output:

1] Fix the interval for the Axis so the axis label and Grid lines do not change.

```
a.AxisX.Interval = 1;
```

2] Fix the bar width for the series. You can use `PixelPointWidth` to specify the width in Pixels or `PointWidth` in Points.

Example using `PixelPointWidth`:

```
s["PixelPointWidth"] = "20";
```

Also, since you are using `c.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;` to fill the chart into whole form, fixed width will not be good if you scale the form.
You can use `MinPixelPointWidth` and `MaxPixelPointWidth` to give the range to the width.

```
s["MinPixelPointWidth"] = "20";
s["MaxPixelPointWidth"] = "80";
```

Check this link for details on [different chart elements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456696(v=vs.100).aspx).
[Technical Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456726(v=vs.110).aspx) for detailed documentation on Chart controls. This may be long but important to understand the details.